# Avoid recommendations in youku video

Tags: video, iframe, embed

I am embedding youku video in my site.
once the video is played, Youku video is giving recommendation of other videos.
so please let me know how to avoid those recomended videos

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the following within your YKU.Player object:

`show_related: false`

Comment: what about iframe method?